# List value getting replaced with new ones

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I am having an input

```
5.3,3.6,1.6,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.3,1.6,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.3,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.3,1.6,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.3,3.6,1.6,0.3,Iris-setosa
```

And I am having a List

```
BinList {3=[index=0 {from=1.3,to=1.42}, index=1 {from=1.42,to=1.5399999999999998}, index=2 {from=1.5399999999999998,to=1.6599999999999997}, index=3 {from=1.6599999999999997,to=1.7799999999999996}, index=4 {from=1.7799999999999996,to=1.8999999999999995}, index=5 {from=1.8999999999999995,to=1.9}], 2=[index=0 {from=2.9,to=3.2399999999999998}, index=1 {from=3.2399999999999998,to=3.5799999999999996}, index=2 {from=3.5799999999999996,to=3.9199999999999995}, index=3 {from=3.9199999999999995,to=4.26}, index=4 {from=4.26,to=4.6}, index=5 {from=4.6,to=4.6}], 1=[index=0 {from=4.3,to=4.62}, index=1 {from=4.62,to=4.94}, index=2 {from=4.94,to=5.260000000000001}, index=3 {from=5.260000000000001,to=5.580000000000001}, index=4 {from=5.580000000000001,to=5.9}], 4=[index=0 {from=0.3,to=0.36}, index=1 {from=0.36,to=0.42}, index=2 {from=0.42,to=0.48}, index=3 {from=0.48,to=0.54}, index=4 {from=0.54,to=0.6}]}
```

where for example

```
3=[index=0 {from=1.3,to=1.42}, index=1 {from=1.42,to=1.5399999999999998}, index=2 {from=1.5399999999999998,to=1.6599999999999997}, index=3 {from=1.6599999999999997,to=1.7799999999999996}, index=4 {from=1.7799999999999996,to=1.8999999999999995}, index=5 {from=1.8999999999999995,to=1.9}]
```

`key 3` represents the `column number` and the `value` represents the `Index` and `range`.

so  for example

```
5.3,3.6,1.6,0.3,Iris-setosa
```

this should be replaced with the index values.

```
3,2,2,0,Iris-setosa
```

So far what I did is

I found the indexes and tried to add the identified index to a List.
But my list is not getting updated.and I am not able appened the last token in List
I am getting correct index.
code

```
List<String> mapList = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, List<Attribute>> binList = new HashMap<String, List<Attribute>>();

//mapList contains the input value
for (String temp : mapList) {
System.out.println("temp: "+temp);

//Setting column number for inputdata
int indexMap=1;
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(temp,",");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
String token = st.nextToken();
System.out.println("token ()"+token);

//Checking to find same column number in list
List<String> mapFinalList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Attribute>> entry : binList.entrySet())
{

     //Key similarity
 if(entry.getKey().equals(String.valueOf(indexMap))){

  System.out.println("equal"+entry.getKey()+"=="+indexMap);

  //Iterating through the values of found out key
  for (Attribute a : entry.getValue())
         {

            //Parsing the values
            ParseValue.parse(a).toString();
            int index = ParseValue.getIndex();
            double  rangeFrom = ParseValue.getrangeFrom();
            double rangeTo = ParseValue.getrangeTo();


             //  Condition Checking for bins
            if((Double.parseDouble(token) <= rangeTo)&& (Double.parseDouble(token) < rangeTo)){
              System.out.println("replace: "+index);
              if(mapFinalList == null) {
                mapFinalList = new ArrayList<String>();
                 }

              mapFinalList.add(String.valueOf(index));
              System.out.println("List "+mapFinalList);
              break;

              }//if loop

            }//for loop
          }//if loop

        }//for loop

       indexMap++;

      }//while

    }//for
```

Output

```
In BinningInput
5.3,3.6,1.6,0.3,Iris-setosa
temp: 5.3,3.6,1.6,0.3,Iris-setosa
token ()5.3
equal1==1
replace: 3
List [3]
token ()3.6
equal2==2
replace: 2
List [2]
token ()1.6
equal3==3
replace: 2
List [2]
token ()0.3
equal4==4
replace: 0
List [0]
token ()Iris-setosa
```

Please Suggest.

Comment: You mean to say your values are getting replaced everytime you add an index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop, you are instantiating the List in every iteration at the line

```
 List<String> mapFinalList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

After this you add your value to the list. So on every iteration, a new list is created and the values from the last iteration is lost. The new list will contain the value inserted in the current loop. So the list contains only the current value and the last values are lost. What you need to do instead is, create a list outside the for loop and instantiate the list just once and use the same instance for all iterations. This way, the values are added one after the other and won't be replaced.

Comment: What about the `if(mapFinalList == null) {` in the line above that?

Comment: I was referring to the `mapFinalList = new ArrayList<String>();` in the outer for loop. I have edited the code to show the complete line.

Comment: Oh, you are right! I did not notice those other two layers of loops at all, due to poor indentation...

Comment: I am trying to get  index values of each line as each list

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni Sorry.. I didn't understand that comment. Could you explain what exactly it is that you need.